# Problems with grab tool in Sculpt mode specifically trying to lock the sphere while grabbing

Tags: sculpting

Hello so whenever I try to use the grab brush like in the gif I provide it moves the whole object but when the video model does it only the specific part she chooses gets grabbed and changed not the whole sphere. I wanted to know if there is a setting that should be turned on or off. I checked everywhere and cannot find a solution. First gif is the creator and the second gift is mine.  [image][image]

Answer (score 0):

The brush radius appears to be too large. You can adjust it by pressing the <kbd>F</kbd> shortcut.
If you are using a pen tablet, you can also enable pressure.
[image: radius menu]

Comment: Hello yes thank you for commenting. I understand that the brush radius is large but in the original creators gif you can see they also have it at 500 radius but their sphere doesnt move either. Also I dont see where I can enable pressure or increase it for the pen in blender?

Comment: @DarkEyeRichi The same set radius maybe, but this is the size in pixels in the viewport, so whenever you zoom in or out it gets larger or smaller relative to the mesh. The tutor has an outer circle that looks about the height of the mesh, while you have an inner circle smaller than the mesh and an outer circle more than twice the size...

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann Ah yes I see what you are saying my radius is over the whole sphere while the tutor has theirs at the the bottom point even with 500 radius. So should I be zoomed out more when I work on it or should I be adjusting something else? Thank you for replying.

Comment: @DarkEyeRichi That is completely up to you, there is no right or wrong in this case. You just have to know of course it makes a difference if you just cover part of the mesh or the whole mesh with your brush. When using a large brush you probably have to zoom in more to cover a smaller area. When using a smaller brush you have to zoom out to cover a larger area. The question then is only if you can see good enough what you're doing on a small mesh when zoomed far out.